# Combination generation algorithm detail

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, combinations

The code below works, displaying a list of combinations. However, I can't figure out why switching the order of the two recursive calls in `comb_util` breaks the code. Why is this? It looks to me like they shouldn't interfere with each other at all as they print combinations.

```js
function combinations(arr, n, r) {
  var data = [];
  comb_util(arr, n, r, 0, data, 0);
}

function comb_util(arr, n, r, index_data, data, index_arr) {
  if(index_data == r) {
    console.log(data);
    return;
  }
  if(index_arr >= n) {
    return;
  }
  data[index_data] = arr[index_arr];
  comb_util(arr, n, r, index_data + 1, data, index_arr + 1);
  comb_util(arr, n, r, index_data, data, index_arr + 1);
}

var data = [1,2,3,4];
var n = data.length;
var r = 3;
combinations(data, n, r);
```

```js
function combinations(arr, n, r) {
  var data = [];
  comb_util(arr, n, r, 0, data, 0);
}

function comb_util(arr, n, r, index_data, data, index_arr) {
  if(index_data == r) {
    console.log(data);
    return;
  }
  if(index_arr >= n) {
    return;
  }
  data[index_data] = arr[index_arr];
  comb_util(arr, n, r, index_data, data, index_arr + 1);
  comb_util(arr, n, r, index_data + 1, data, index_arr + 1);
}

var data = [1,2,3,4];
var n = data.length;
var r = 3;
combinations(data, n, r);
```

Comment: you use the same global variable data, so they do interfere with each other. Try a few manual examples thinking of how data is filled on both ways

Comment: Thanks, @juvian, I see that now, and that passing a shallow copy of `data` would solve the problem if the lines needed to be switched for some strange reason.